# Is there a way to turn off popups in Notepad++ macros?

Tags: notepad++, macros

I created a macro in Notepad++ that cleans up imported data through a series of regex search and replace iterations.  This works well, but at each step, I get a popup telling me how many instances were replaced.  This means I have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> several times for the macro to run to completion, which is annoying.

Is there any way to turn off these popup notifications while the macro is running?  I haven't been able to find any setting in the application preferences that controls this.

Comment: As of NP++ 6.5.2, the popup has been replaced by a status bar in the Search/Replace dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this in official code. However, if you can apply a patch and compile from source, then you can try the Adjustable Feedback mode patch, available [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3109193&group_id=95717&atid=612384). You might also be interested to contribute to the discussion about that topic [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/ideatorrent/notepad-plus/ideatorrent/idea/213/).

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to patch notepad++

Modify line 932 of ./PowerEditor/src/ScitillaComponent/FindReplaceDlg.cpp

```
::MessageBox(_hParent, result.c_str(), TEXT("Replace All"), MB_OK);
```

You would want to add

```
if !(isMacroPlaying) ::MessageBox(_hParent, result.c_str(), TEXT("Replace All"), MB_OK);
```

But at this time there is no isMacroPlaying.

The generic MessageBox does not have a handler "message" id to interact with during macro play.

Comment: although the adjustable feedback patch is large it is your best bet.